# Escaping slashes when decoding json php

Tags: php

I have a problem when returning a row from database that has a column type `TEXT`(in this case, column "details") which contains an array of JSON objects. Example:

```
{
    productid: 1
    shopid: 1
    title: 'Product 1'
--> details: [{"name":"Brand name","value":"Brand value"},{"name":"Color","value":"blue"}]
    . . .
}
```

Data inserted into database in columns of type `TEXT` are inserted like `addslashes(json_encode($array_or_object))` to safely escape before insert.

When returning data, columns of type `TEXT` by function `json_decode()` and returned with no problem. Problem occurs when someone tries using single `'` and double quotes `"` in `details`. Example:

```
details: [{"name":"\\\"test123\\\"","value":"\\\"test\\\" \\'test\\' \\\"test \\' test \\' t\\\"est"}]
```

Returned value looks like:

```
"details": [
  {
    "name": "\\\"test123\\\"",
    "value": "\\\"test\\\" \\'test\\' \\\"test \\' test \\' t\\\"est"
  }
],
```

I have more than one way of storing `JSON` data in database (as object, array of objects, array of arrays of objects,...), and I need a way to escape these backslashes.

Using `stripslashes()` on the string before using `json_decode()` does not work, it breaks the `JSON`.

Creating a recursive function works, but is not as pretty as I would like it to be. Example:

```
function decode_json($json) {
    if (empty($json)) {
        return $json;
    }
    if (is_string($json)) {
        $json = json_decode($json, true);
    }
    foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $json[$key] = decode_json($value);
            continue;
        }
        $json[$key] = stripslashes($value);
    }
    return $json;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`json_encode` already escape your string, you don't need to use `addslashes()`
Example:

```
$var = ["value" => "test'\""];
print_r(json_encode($var));
```

Result:

> {"value":"test'\""}

And will be better to use PDO with bind parameters: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: "json_encode already escape your string" — for JSON, but if you put the JSON into a string of SQL then it needs escaping again for SQL.

Answer (score 0):

and what exactly is the point of using a database, when storing the raw JSON?

decode first, then escape the values to insert - else you'll also escape all of the JSON delimiters,

which might subsequently cripple the whole input string and render it F.U.B.A.R.

PS: [PDOStatement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) still requires [PDO::quote()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) to escape the input properly.